# libcurl : output of network upload download speed is not accurate

Tags: c++, c, libcurl, bandwidth

I have used libcurl libraries to calculate my network upload download speed. I am using the following codes. But the rate of upload and download is not accurate compared to original network speed. (my output is around 1.3 KBps, 370KBps compared to original 500KBps for upload and 1MBps for download)

It will be very helpful if anyone can tell the reasons for this and what modification should I do to get the proper upload download speed. New procedures to calculate the rates are also welcome.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

size_t write_data(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, FILE *stream) 

{
size_t written = fwrite(ptr, size, nmemb, stream);
return written;
}

int main(void) {
 CURL *curl;
 CURL *curl1;
 FILE *fp;
 CURLcode res;
 CURLcode res1;
 char *url = 
  "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/47/PNG_transparency
  _demonstration_1.png";           
 char outfilename[FILENAME_MAX] = "aaa.jpg";
 curl = curl_easy_init();
 curl1 = curl_easy_init();
 struct stat file_info;
 double speed_upload, total_time1;
 FILE *fd;

 fd = fopen("aaa.jpg", "rb"); 
if(!fd)
  return 1; 

if(fstat(fileno(fd), &file_info) != 0)
  return 1;  

if(curl1) {
  curl_easy_setopt(curl1, CURLOPT_URL,
                  "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/47/PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png");            
curl_easy_setopt(curl1, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 1L);

curl_easy_setopt(curl1, CURLOPT_READDATA, fd);

curl_easy_setopt(curl1, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE_LARGE,(curl_off_t)file_info.st_size);

curl_easy_setopt(curl1, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);

res1 = curl_easy_perform(curl1);
/* Check for errors */ 
if(res1 != CURLE_OK) {
  fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
          curl_easy_strerror(res1));

}
else {
  curl_easy_getinfo(curl1, CURLINFO_SPEED_UPLOAD, &speed_upload);
  curl_easy_getinfo(curl1, CURLINFO_TOTAL_TIME, &total_time1);

  fprintf(stderr, "Speed: %.3f bytes/sec during %.3f seconds\n",
          speed_upload, total_time1);

}
curl_easy_cleanup(curl1);
fclose(fd);
}
if (curl) {
    fp = fopen(outfilename,"wb");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, write_data);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, fp);
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

if (CURLE_OK == res) {
    double val;

    res = curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_SIZE_DOWNLOAD, &val);
    if ((CURLE_OK == res) && (val>0))
        printf("Data downloaded: %0.0f bytes.\n", val);

    res = curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_TOTAL_TIME, &val);
    if ((CURLE_OK == res) && (val>0))
        printf("Total download time: %0.3f sec.\n", val);

    res = curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_SPEED_DOWNLOAD, &val);
    if ((CURLE_OK == res) && (val>0))
        printf("Average download speed: %0.3f kbyte/sec.\n", val / 1024);

}
else {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error while fetching '%s' : %s\n",
        url, curl_easy_strerror(res));
}
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    fclose(fp);
}
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no perfect solution to your problem. You cannot accurately measure your provider's network speed by transferring an image to/from Wikipedia, because this involves also Wikipedia's own network, and the Internet backbone between you and Wikipedia. You are not the only user of the Internet, so your bandwidth is shared with many others. So when you transfer an image to/from Wikipedia, the speed you get is just an instantenous measurement of the network conditions between you and Wikipedia, and if you repeat it one minute later you will likely get different results.

The PNG you are accessing is not very big, at 1 megabyte/second it only takes one fifth of a second to transfer. However, before the actual download starts your computer has to perform a DNS lookup for `upload.wikimedia.org`, then create a TCP connection to Wikipedia's servers, set up encryption using TLS, send the request for the image, and only then will you the actual transfer of the image start. It is likely that some time spent setting up the connection is also counted against the transfer speed as measured by Curl. You will get better results by using bigger files, but if you are going to run this speed test often, be aware that Wikipedia might not like you wasting their bandwidth.

There are dedicated sites to help you measure your provider's speed. Just search for "http speed test" and you will find several.